# run some php files automatically when apache starts

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP file that always listens to a socket, 
I must have a tab opened in my browser to execute that file, 
Is there a way to define some PHP files to apache to execute automatically when apache starts?

Comment: Heard of cron jobs..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: I want to run just one time when apache starts, it has a while and it doesn't need to run periodical with cron jobs @웃웃웃웃웃

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to check this article:
http://webadvent.org/2009/daemonize-your-php-by-sean-coates

It recommends to install `supervisord` to make sure that one instance of your php script is running. It's something that you would make frequently when working with async job queues.